# existence of faithful pure states

Tags: representation-theory, examples-counterexamples, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. By Krein-Milman the set of pure states of $A$, $P(A)$, is always non-empty. For a step in a proof I need the existence of a faithful pure state $f\in P(A)$.

Does such a $f$ always exist?

Instead of asking for the existence of faithful pure states one can ask for existence of faithful irreducible $*$-representations. 
Sadly I have no idea if the answer is yes or no, so I appreciate your ideas.

Comment: If we take, for example, $A=C([0,1])$, then you know that pure states are exactly evaluations. You can always find a non-zero positive function which is zero on "the evaluated point" of your state. So, generally "such a $f$ " does not exist. However, I'm not sure in which cases we have faithful pure states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Pure" is kind of the opposite of "faithful".

As Shirly mentioned, if $A$ is abelian then all irreducible representations are 1-dimensional. So the only abelian C$^*$-algebra with a faithful pure state is $\mathbb C$.

And whenever $A$ is arbitrary, if $\phi$ is a faithful pure state,  both faithfulness and pureness of the state survive to subalgebras. In particular, $\phi$ will also be pure and faithful on all abelian subalgebras (there are always many of this, take any normal $a\in A$ and consider $C^*(a)\subset A$). So all abelian subalgebras are trivial. This means that any selfadjoint $a\in A$ has single-point spectrum, i.e. it is a scalar multiple of the identity. As selfadjoints span $A$, this applies to all elements.

In summary, the only C$^*$-algebra with a faithful pure state is $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Wait a minute. If $A$ is simple, then *all* states are faithful, including all the pure states. What's going wrong here?

Comment: @Johannes: The pure states of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ are the maps $$A\longmapsto\langle Ax,x\rangle,$$ which are never faithful.

Comment: Well, then I obviously misremembered what faithful means for states.

Comment: It means that $\phi(a^*a)=0$ implies $a=0$. The canonical faithful state on $M_n(\mathbb C)$ is the trace.

Comment: Thanks. In that case I completely agree with your proof.